# When the functions are passed as props, is the shopping cart unable to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, shopping-cart

I am in the process of creating a shopping page which contains an array of items, I have also implemented functions such as "addToCart", "removeFromCart", "increaseQuantity" and "decreaseQuantity". However, when I pass these values as a prop to the cart page, I encounter an issue where after selecting the cart title from the navbar the page fails to render properly "It shows a blank screen". Despite having checked my methods using console logs, I am still unable to determine the root cause of the issue!

Here's the react.js code:

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, } from 'react-router-dom';
import Shop from './Components/Pages/A-Shop/Shop';
import Cart from './Components/Pages/Cart'
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
function App() {

  return (

    <div className='App'>

      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <
          <Route path='/Shop' element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />

          <Route path='*' element={<ErrorPage />} />

        </Routes>

      </Router>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

NavBar.js:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
    return (
        <nav>
            <NavLink to="/" id="title"> Clean energy for business</NavLink>

            <div>
                <ul id='navbar'>
                    <NavItem to='/' label='Home' />
                    <NavItem to='/Shop' label='Shop' />
                    <NavItem to='/Profile' label='Profile' />
                    <NavItem to='/Cart' label='Cart' />

                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav >
    );
}

function NavItem({ to, label }) {
    return (
        <li>
            <NavLink to={to} activeClassName='active'>
                {label}
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Shop.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Cart from '../Cart';


function Shop() {
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

    const items = [
        { id: 1, name: 'T-shirt', price: 25, image: 'images/Shop/6.png' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Patch', price: 10, image: 'images/Shop/4.PNG' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Cap', price: 20, image: 'images/Shop/3.png' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Bandana', price: 15, image: 'images/Shop/2.png' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Bag', price: 20, image: 'images/Shop/1.png' },
        { id: 6, name: 'Socks', price: 20, image: 'images/Shop/5.png' }
    ];

    const addToCart = (item) => {
        const index = cartItems.findIndex((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);
        if (index === -1) {
            setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...item, quantity: 1 }]);
        } else {
            const newCartItems = [...cartItems];
            newCartItems[index].quantity++;
            setCartItems(newCartItems);
        }
    };

    const removeFromCart = (item) => {
        const newCartItems = [...cartItems];
        const index = newCartItems.findIndex((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);
        newCartItems.splice(index, 1);
        setCartItems(newCartItems);
    };

    const increaseQuantity = (item) => {
        const newCartItems = [...cartItems];
        const index = newCartItems.findIndex((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);
        newCartItems[index].quantity++;
        setCartItems(newCartItems);
    };

    const decreaseQuantity = (item) => {
        const newCartItems = [...cartItems];
        const index = newCartItems.findIndex((cartItem) => cartItem.id === item.id);
        if (newCartItems[index].quantity > 1) {
            newCartItems[index].quantity--;
            setCartItems(newCartItems);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='Shop'>
            <h1 className='shop-title'>Shopping Page</h1>
            <div className="item-list">
                {items.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id} className="item">
                        <img className='shop-image' src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <p>£{item.price}</p>
                        <button className='shop-button' onClick={() => addToCart(item)}>Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <Cart
                cartItems={cartItems}
                removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
                increaseQuantity={increaseQuantity}
                decreaseQuantity={decreaseQuantity}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Shop;
```

Cart.js:

```
const Cart = (props) => {
    const cartItems = props.cartItems;
    const removeFromCart = props.removeFromCart;
    const increaseQuantity = props.increaseQuantity;
    const decreaseQuantity = props.decreaseQuantity;
    return (
        <div className='Cart'>
            <h1 className='cart-title'>Cart Page</h1>
            <div className="cart-items">
                {cartItems.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id} className="cart-item">
                        <img className='cart-image' style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }} src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <p>£{item.price}</p>
                        <p>Quantity: {item.quantity}</p>
                        <button className='cart---button' onClick={() => increaseQuantity(item)}>+</button>
                        <button className='cart---button' onClick={() => decreaseQuantity(item)}>-</button>
                        <button className='cart-remove-button' onClick={() => removeFromCart(item)}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default Cart;
```

I have tried console log the code, and it shows that the code is functional, but still I don't understand why I can't render the cart page.

Comment: You are rendering `Cart` in two locations, one in the `Shop` component where props are passed to it, and another on a discrete route without any props passed to it. Where do you really want `Cart` rendered in relation to the `Shop` component?

Comment: I would like to add the cart component to the navbar so that users can easily access it. For example, when a user clicks on the cart title in the navbar, they should be able to view the contents of the cart page.

Comment: So do you need to render a `Cart` component in `Shop`? Do you need to render a `Cart` on its own route? Render `Cart` in the navbar? Are you saying you just want to render a link to `"/cart"` in the navbar, and the cart on its own route, nothing in `Shop`?

Comment: well I only want to render the cart component on the navbar, or in other word I want to pass in the methods e.g., "removeFromCart", "increaseQuantity" from shop to cart and render them over there in cart. Hope that makes sense ;)

Comment: Then I suppose you lift state up to the `App` component, render `Cart` in `NavBar`, and pass all the props/callbacks down to `NavBar` to pass to `Cart`. Remove the `"/cart"` route and remove `Cart` from `Shop`.

Comment: oh, I see, u know I tried something similar but instead of rendering them in the navbar, I rendered them in app.js, however, I was able to see the cart page on the navbar but the page was not functional!

Comment: Mr. Drew Reese, could you please provide me with some additional context to help me integrate your solution into mine? Thank you very much!

Comment: In the interest of saving time, do you think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could run and inspect live? I suspect also that you don't ***really*** want to render the actual `Cart` component in the `NavBar`, but that you want the `<NavItem to='/cart' label='Cart' />` to link to the `"/cart"` route and display there. There's a few ways to render content in multiple places.

Comment: Hey Drew Reese! You're awesome! Everything is working perfectly now and I can see all the changes in the cart page. The only issue was that I was passing the props to the cart.js component incorrectly. This time, I added them in app.js and it rendered perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and keep up the fantastic work!

Answer (score 0):

You can Add this condition on Shop.js:

```
{cartItems.length > 0 &&
<Cart
                cartItems={cartItems}
                removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
                increaseQuantity={increaseQuantity}
                decreaseQuantity={decreaseQuantity}
            />
}
```

Cart.js

```
const Cart = (props) => {
    const cartItems = props.cartItems;
    const removeFromCart = props.removeFromCart;
    const increaseQuantity = props.increaseQuantity;
    const decreaseQuantity = props.decreaseQuantity;
    return (
        <div className='Cart'>
            <h1 className='cart-title'>Cart Page</h1>
            <div className="cart-items">
                {cartItems.length > 0 && cartItems.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id} className="cart-item">
                        <img className='cart-image' style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }} src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <p>£{item.price}</p>
                        <p>Quantity: {item.quantity}</p>
                        <button className='cart---button' onClick={() => increaseQuantity(item)}>+</button>
                        <button className='cart---button' onClick={() => decreaseQuantity(item)}>-</button>
                        <button className='cart-remove-button' onClick={() => removeFromCart(item)}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default Cart;
```

Comment: yeah I tired that but, I'm getting the same error, like the cart page still shows a blank page :,)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and have the following findings. Your cart component is working fine when you are rendering it from inside Shop component. Because you are passing the necessary props to it. [image: Cart Components with props]

But when you are trying to render the Cart component independently from routes, you are not passing the props to the components. That's why it is giving error when you are trying to load that route (/cart). [image: Cart component issue]

**Solution -** You need to use global store like redux or context to make all the selected items available on the separate route. and make the cart component independent of props.

Comment: Thx mate I might as well try that